# for background removal: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'output' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

I am trying to blur the video to detect the persons only, I am following the KDnuggets steps.
but I am getting the below error.

```py
import pixellib
from pixellib.tune_bg import alter_bg

change_bg = alter_bg(model_type = "pb")
change_bg.load_pascalvoc_model("xception_pascalvoc.pb")

change_bg = change_bg.blur_video(video_path="Cut52-1.mp4", extreme = True, frames_per_second=10, output_video_name="blur2_video.mp4", detect = "person")
```

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'output' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Do you have more relevant code to show?

Comment: there must be more logic in order to get the error you received (ie. there's no reference to name `output`); if there's no more, try resetting your kernel if you're using an IPython notebook

Comment: You didn't provide a full stack trace, but from the code you shared, it would appear that the error is occurring inside one of these functions and you're missing some required setup (although error message could be clearer and this type of error is kinda nasty)

Comment: The code is shared by KDnuggets but it is not working and I have still did not know why. https://www.kdnuggets.com/2020/12/change-background-video-5-lines-code.html

Answer (score 0):

should be:

```
output = change_bg.blur_video(video_path="Cut52-1.mp4", extreme = True, frames_per_second=10, output_video_name="blur2_video.mp4", detect = "person")
```